# Find not direct element

Tags: html, css

Edit: Please take note that the number of parent divs may vary. It may be one or more.

I am trying everything to get the parent `<div>` of a `<div>` with class `rat` that contains a label. So in this case, the outermost `<div>` must be returned.

```
<div> --> Should be returned
    <div>  
        <div class="item box1" id="box1">1</div>
        <div class="item" id="box2">2</div>
        <div class="item" id="box3">3</div>
        <div class="item rat" id="box4">4</div> 
    </div>
    <label>Im the original parent</label>
</div>
```

It can easily be done when I add class attributes for each div and use `closest()` but for this case there's no unique selector that I can use.

Or we can take it this way: find the closest label of the `<div>` with class `rat` using the above example:

```
$('.rat') -> selector
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: @pwolaq sorry the case is different

Comment: I think you won't be able to do this without JS. There is no CSS selector that will do that.

Comment: Do you peviously know how deep is your `rat` element? Is it always two levels deep or it may vary?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi i updated my question, it will vary. What I have in mind is to recursively check all parents and stop until I found a parent that contains a label tag

Comment: The given HTML doesn't match what you'r trying to do.

Comment: If the number of parent `divs` may vary,  than show us another possible structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive approach is the most suitable for your required behavior:

```js
function getParentWithLabel(className) {
    function climbRecusively(node) {
        const parent = node.parent();
        return (parent.find('> label').length ? parent : climbRecusively(parent));
    }
    return climbRecusively($(`.${className}`));
}

$(function() {
    getParentWithLabel('rat').css('background-color', 'grey');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>  
        <div class="item box1" id="box1">1</div>
        <div class="item" id="box2">2</div>
        <div class="item" id="box3">3</div>
        <div class="item rat" id="box4">4</div> 
    </div>
    <label>Im the original parent</label>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks!, the one im looking for. Ill modify on my end to satisfy my actual requirement or maybe some optimization if any

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be easier if you apply your style in your global jQuery, like this :

```
$('.rat').parent().next();
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that the number of parent divs may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this too

```
   var parentEls = $( ".rat" ).parents();

parentEls.each(function (i, obj) {
    if($(obj).find( "> label" ).length){
    console.log($(obj).attr('class'));
  }
});
```

Full example : http://jsfiddle.net/harshakj89/ey00czfn/1/

Comment: the idea is correct but it will fail once i nested my element with a lot of divs :)

Comment: i've edited the answer. would you be able to check it? @Sherlock